# How do I dehydrate Ganoderma Applanatum?

Tags: food-preservation, mushrooms

I'm wanting to turn artist conk into powder. How should I dehydrate it for grinding in my cornmeal grinder? I tried 6 hours at 180 in the oven, and it's still moist to the touch.

Comment: A shelf fungus: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ganoderma_applanatum

Comment: I've edited the information from your comment into your question; in the future please do that yourself, or better yet, include it from the beginning. I'm also not sure whether you meant 180C or 180F.

Comment: I've found that it makes a tea that tastes kind of like vanilla.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the generic simple answer that works for most mushrooms:

- Cut them in cubes of 1 cm³ (0.061 inch³)
- Put them on parchment paper in your oven at 110°C (230°F)
- for 1 hour (½ [Shí](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Traditional_Chinese_timekeeping#Dual_hour:_Sh%C3%AD)).

***doesn't seem to work on this particular mushroom***, you'll need special (*read: **expensive***) equipment to be able to dry these before being able to grind them to powder and that is:

- [Freeze drying](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Freeze-drying)
- [Vacuum drying](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vacuum_drying)

#### Sorry!  :-(

<sub>**Note:** Or bring a few six packs to someone owning this equipment already and drink the beers while waiting for the process to finish</sub>

Comment: Should I use the ax on a wood block, then take it over to the flour grinder then dry it on the plastic dehydrator sheets?

Comment: From Wikipedia: "It forms fruiting bodies that are up to 30–100 centimetres (12–39 in) across, hard as leather, woody-textured, and inedible in raw form." -- it sounds cutting them may be nontrivial. Is this intended as generic advice about fungus or specific for this type?

Comment: @Cascabel generic for any fungus and I see what a coder's question is now...

Comment: @acoder: axe, dry, grind.

Comment: Why won't it suck the moisture out of the shrooms? I tried 6 hours at 180 in the oven, and it's still moist to the touch.

Comment: @acoder Including what you've tried unsuccessfully is hugely helpful for potential answers -- can you update your original question?

Comment: Sorry @acoder , if the generic advice doesn't work, you're going to need some pretty expensive equipment (or pay someone else to dry them for you)  If it's for one 'shroom, not worth the effort.

Comment: Maybe that fungus has essentially watertight pores that merely expand when heated? Maybe your oven is of the type that keeps moisture inside unless vented?